# What does "never mind that" mean?

Tags: meaning

The dictionary says that it means: "despite the fact that", but I also thought it could also mean "forget about that". Is it the case or I was just mistaken?

I thought about an example like this:

> Is my sister with you? Is she ok?
>
> Do you want to speak to her? She's next to me.
>
> Never mind that, instead tell me if you bought the presents for Christmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Never mind that" refers to something someone says to you.

- Look at all this food! [one person says]
- Never mind **that** [the previous sentence], where're the plates? [another responds]

Never mind means: I don't care about what you just said. I am interested in what I have to say: where are the plates?

In the OP's example, he is not interested in talking about his sister, he wants to know: about the Christmas presents.

That is what is called a deictic pronoun. It refers to something already said.

Comment: It may also mean "Ignore what I just said"; either because you want to correct yourself, or because new information has become available.